# Import raw photos from Photos app

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, photos.app

I took a picture on an iPhone in raw format with the camera app.

When I use the macOS Photos app, dragging the photo thumbnail  to the desktop converts it to jpeg.

Is there a way to export photos in raw format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[X_841](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/355336/x-841) is correct.

- In Photos, select the RAW image or images that you want to export.
- Under the File Menu, select Export, then select Export Unmodified Original.
- Save the file where ever you choose.

That file will be save out in it's unmodified RAW format.