# How does one download raw pictures (images) as files from an iPhone, without using apple's photo app (to my macbook pro)?

Tags: iphone, photos, photos.app, facebook, image-capture

It's annoying how apple tries to manage your photos automatically. Then it's hard to find the photos and do whatever I want with them - e.g. upload to facebook, have a normal file interface instead of their enforced photo app interface etc.

How does one do this?

I was able to find the location of the folders but it's a mess, the folders are named 0 1 2 etc and then they don't seem to be correctly organized. I want to download the pictures myself and not have apple automatically sync my phone with my mac - especially since my phone has less storage space.

---

Related:

- [Import raw photos from Photos app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411902/import-raw-photos-from-photos-app)

Comment: My answer here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/434447/backup-copy-pictures-and-files-from-an-iphone-or-ipad-to-a-pc-in-a-reasonable/434457#434457 may help.

Comment: cross posted: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-does-one-download-raw-pictures-images-as-files-from-an-iPhone-without-a-USI

Answer (score 1):

To be able to download the pictures raw without the need of photo app do the following:

1. Open **image capture**
2. Make sure your phone is unlocked, you click trusted etc.
3. Select the pictures you want to download and place them in a folder in your computer. I recommend not using the `Pictures` folder since that seems to get sync automatically with your iphone (without permission sometimes) and then it's annoying to remove them from your phone.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=41&v=GQHRbu-Fysk&feature=emb_title but decided to write it out in case the link ever dies.